# Why do Python's set seem to perform worse than arrays

Tags: python-2.7, performance-testing

I was testing the performance of "in set" vs "in array". And my tests showed that arrays were faster. Why would that be the case?

Here's my tests and output:
https://gist.github.com/mozeryansky/4a0872e9b2ff6e1704d07426ba829ea4

Answer (score 1):

You're including the cost of creating the set or list in your timings. (Also, Python calls `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` a list, not an array.)

Comment: Either way, python will need to create the set or list when running. Why would there be such a huge difference?

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: The idea is that you're supposed to create the set once and then use it for a bunch of lookups, not create a set every time you want to do a lookup.

Comment: The test case I'm testing against is running a python file multiple times, so my actual use case would be creating the set multiple times.

Comment: Are you saying sets are only more efficient if I do multiple lookups?

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky: If you only use the set once, you spend more time making it than you save on the lookup.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky The point of using a set for membership checking is to avoid the need to perform a linear scan over the data. Obviously you *do* need to do a full scan over the data to create the set to begin with. Furthermore, when you are creating the set, you are doing something much more complicated with the elements than simply checking them for equality with the target value (you are applying a hash function and storing the hashes in a hash table).